# Register domain with country Code

Tags: domain

im planning to register a domain , im yet to register before that i have a query , ok .
so what i need to do is register a domain country specific like say www.in.webtechar.com for india , www.uk.webtechar.com for UK and so on ... ok is this can be achieved with one single domain www.webtechar.com or ill have to register a country specific domain for each country
e.g. http://www.in.capgemini.com/

THanks,
Mukesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registrations will mostly be based on the last bit of the domain i.e. the .com, what you want to do can be achieved by setting up subdomains on your web server.

Answer (score 1):

The domain is the name.com part.  Everything before the name is host-specific.  So if everything you want to do is something.webtechar.com, you only have to register webtechar.com.

If you were doing country-specific top level domains like webtechar.in or webtechar.uk, then you would need to register each one of those.